# pig latin - load with text qualifier

Tags: text, load, apache-pig, qualifiers

I am trying to load a datafile in a pig latin script,
Data has 2 columns but there is a text qualifier in the 2nd column and sample data is below :

```
DEVICE_ID,SUPPORTED_TECH
a2334,"GSM900,GSM1500,GSM200"
a54623,"GSM900,GSM1500"
a86646,"GSM1500,GSM200"
```

When I try loading the date as below, 2nd column is not recognized as 1 column

```
deviceList = load 'deviceList.csv' Using PigStorage(',') as (DEVICE_ID:chararray, SUPPORTED_TECH:chararray );
```

How can I define the text qualifier while loading the data set ?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , let me know if you need different output format

**input.txt**

```
DEVICE_ID,SUPPORTED_TECH
a2334,"GSM900,GSM1500,GSM200"
a54623,"GSM900,GSM1500"
a86646,"GSM1500,GSM200
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS line;
deviceList = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'^(\\w+),(.*)$')) as (DEVICE_ID:chararray, SUPPORTED_TECH:chararray );
DUMP deviceList;
```

**OutPut:**

```
(DEVICE_ID,SUPPORTED_TECH)
(a2334,"GSM900,GSM1500,GSM200")
(a54623,"GSM900,GSM1500")
(a86646,"GSM1500,GSM200")
```

Comment: thnx for the answer
this works for 2 columns but my original file has 625 columns
can you reccomend anything without defining each column ?